# How to detect when user has scrolled to top of ListView and pass touch through ListView if so?

Tags: android, android-listview

In Android, how would you detect when a user has already scrolled to the top of a listView and is dragging down on the screen even when he has reached the top of the `ListView`, then pass this touch through the `ListView` into the parent `ViewGroup`?

Answer (score 2):

Following snippet will help you to detect top overscroll as well as below overscroll of `ListView`,

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            private static final float OVERSCROLL_THRESHOLD_IN_PIXELS = 100;

            private float downY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int firstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int totalItemCount = listView.getCount();
                int visibleItemCount = listView.getChildCount();
                boolean onTop = firstVisibleItem == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0) != null && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                boolean onBottom = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && listView.getChildAt(visibleItemCount-1).getBottom() == listView.getHeight();

                if(onTop || onBottom) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        downY = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float deltaY = event.getY() - downY;
                        if(onTop && deltaY > OVERSCROLL_THRESHOLD_IN_PIXELS) 
                        {

                            // Top overscroll
                        }
                        if(onBottom && -deltaY > OVERSCROLL_THRESHOLD_IN_PIXELS) {
                            // Bottom overscroll
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but **float deltaY = event.getY() - downY;** does this statement has any chance to throw null pointer exception? Because of **downY**

Comment: @kaze: I have never experienced it.On which circumstance it will be null you think? I am curious.

Comment: if **case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:** condition is called before **case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:** condition, because in the **ACTION_DOWN:** condition only you have initialized the value of **downY**. Before that **downY** have not been assinged to any value. OR is it like that **ACTION_DOWN:** condition is always called 1st before **ACTION_MOVE:** condition atleast once.. in any event

Comment: Technically `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` means **New touch started** and 
`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` means **Finger is moving** . So `ACTION_DOWN` will always be called before `ACTION_MOVE`.

Answer (score 0):

Override the method [onOverScrolled,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) to respond to the results of an over-scroll operation. In you case you need the event when user reached top and over scrolling the list.